# exec() not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php, exec

I have a PHP script in which I need to execute a shell script 'add_article.sh' which reads a parameter file and adds the news article contents to a search index (Lemur/Indri).

Executing the 'add_article.sh' script on its own (from the shell) works perfectly, but running it from within the php script I get this:

```
$blah = exec("./add_article.sh", $out, $ret_val);

echo $out . "<BR />";
echo $ret_val . "<BR />";
```

This produces

*Array*
*255*

It is in the correct directory and fails even with an absolute path. I use exactly the same format in another function in the same file that executes another script in the same directory and all is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I run the script from the shell it outputs 5 or 6 lines of text, through exec I get nothing, also, the return/exit value is 255, anyone know what that means?

Comment: Most likely it means that the script tried to do an `exit -1` or something similar.  This could possibly be useful, if you see someplace in the script where that's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the execute permissions of your shell script? Apache runs as a user with very few permissions in most operating systems, so that may be the cause.

Comment: Yes, the scripts are chmod 777, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Comment: UPDATE: It turned out to be a permissions issue.  My scripts needed to access files in ANOTHER directory that I forgot about and apache didn't have permissions for that directory. Changing permissions for the fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`$out` is supposed to be an array.  You should probably `print_r()` or `var_dump()` it to see what's coming back from the script; it may be telling you what's going wrong.

In general, there's probably some environmental dependency that isn't being satisfied when PHP is running the script.  This is especially common if it's being run from inside Apache.

Comment: This is what var_dump() returns: array(0) { }

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$blah = exec("./add_article.sh", $out, $ret_val);

print_r($out);
echo '<br />';
echo $ret_val . "<br />";
```